# Unity - Quaternion.Lerp - Wheel rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one problem in script(Unity) that I made for car controller. When I want to rotate front wheels of car, example I'm pressing 'A' or 'D' wheels will turn on left or right(0,45 or -45,0) and immediately it will turn on starting rotation(0,0,0), I didn't have this problem when I didn't use Quaternion.Lerp, without Quaternion.Lerp it works fine. Any kind of help will be welcome.

```
//Rotation - WHEELS
            CurrentRotation = Horizontal * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (CurrentRotation <= MaximumRotation || CurrentRotation >= -MaximumRotation)
            {
                Vector3 from_v = new Vector3(Wheels[0].transform.localRotation.x, Wheels[0].transform.localRotation.y, Wheels[0].transform.localRotation.z);
                Vector3 to_v = new Vector3(Wheels[1].transform.localRotation.x, CurrentRotation, Wheels[1].transform.localRotation.z);
                Quaternion from = Quaternion.Euler(from_v);
                Quaternion to = Quaternion.Euler(to_v);
                float lerp = 0.5F * (1.0F + Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * Time.realtimeSinceStartup * 3f));
                Wheels[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, lerp);
                Wheels[1].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from, to, lerp);
            }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using quaternions here instead of Euler angles (particularly considering you are starting and ending with Euler angles in the first place)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Is it the rolling of the wheel plus steering?
Quaternions are great, but here you don't need them. You can get and set the Euler (main axis) rotation directly. Untested code:

```
Vector3 rot = Wheels[0].localRotation;
rot.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
rot.y = (current smoothed steering angle)
Wheels[0].localRotation = rot;
Wheels[1].localRotation = rot;
```

You should orient all your wheel game objects to point x-Axis to the right and Y-Axis to the top. The smoothing / max angles can depend on the input type / device, the game settings and the car speed.

It would be nice if you upvote my answer so I finally can write comments here.

Kind Regards,
Chris